# Index contains duplicate entries after drop_duplicates called

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, dataframe, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that has duplicate entries and I want to create a `tsplot` using `seaborn`.  I call `drop_duplicates` on the dataframe (and even call `reset_index()`) yet when I got to do the plot I still get

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Is there a reason why `drop_duplicates` wouldn't solve this problem?

**EDIT**  I've even checked by calling `duplicated` on the dataframe after the drop, and all rows show `False`.  As I would expect.

I realize there's not much here to go off of, I just wanted to see if there's something intuitive I was missing.  Will try to create a small example to show here but my data set is rather large

Comment: If you cannot show your data, please do at least copy the code you use when trying to drop the duplicates. At the moment it is very hard to help.

Comment: `drop_duplicates` does not work on the index, but on the values in the dataframe! (so it looks for duplicate rows, not duplicate indices). But you also have the same function on the index (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: @joris thanks!  If you write up that answer you'll get the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop_duplicates` does not work on the index, but on the values in the dataframe! (so it looks for duplicate rows, not duplicate indices).

But you also have the same function on the index (see [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html)):

```
df.index.drop_duplicates()
```

With the resulting index, you can reindex.
Another option is to add the index as a column and use `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` on that column.
Another option is to use groupby: `df.groupby(level=0).first()` (and you adapt the `first` to what you want to do with the duplicate rows)